# Get Filename Extension C Error

Tags: c, string

I am using the following function to get the extension of a file in C.

```
int getExt(char *file_name, char *ext) {
    char *p = strrchr(file_name, '.');
    if(p == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    strcpy(ext, p);
    return 1;
}
```

And I am calling it like this:

```
char file_in[40] = "santa.bmp", file_out[40] = "santa.pgn";
char file_in_ext[4], file_out_ext[4];

getExt(file_in, file_in_ext);
getExt(file_out, file_out_ext);

printf("file_in_ext: %s\nfile_out_ext: %s\n", file_in_ext, file_out_ext);
```

And I am getting this following output:

```
file_in_ext: .bmp
file_out_ext: xn.bmp
```

Which obviously is ruining my whole program from that point. However this only happens on the university tester.

Yes, you've guessed right, this is a homework. Nevertheless, my question will not solve my homework. Maybe it's just 0.0001% of a homework task. Therefore I think my question is appropriate.

Anyway, the more curious thing is that on my personal computer, x64 architecture and Debian 7, all works fine. I am getting the correct output:

```
file_in_ext: .bmp
file_out_ext: .pgm
```

I don't really know much about the university tester, just that it's Debian 7.

Do you know why this happens and is there a way to get around this?

Comment: `char file_in_ext[4], file_out_ext[4];` is small.

Comment: You're forgetting either the terminator or the leading `.`. for your extension buffers. `.ext\0` requires 5 chars; not 4.

Comment: Exten ***SSSSSSSSS*** ion...

Comment: Is the ASCII code for `'.'` actually 46?  It would be a lot clearer if you used the character literal notation.

Comment: Then write `'.'` instead of 46; your code is then portable to more machines (there are machines where `'.' == 46` is not true, though you're relatively unlikely to come across them) and your code is more understandable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for pointing that to me. I will sure do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is suffering from **undefined behavior** because of a buffer overflow. You are allocating only 4 characters for your extensions, but the `getExt()` function is writing five: four for `".bmp"` and the fifth is the terminating NULL character.

You should pass in another argument to your `getExt()` function giving the size of the `ext` buffer. Then use `strncpy()` instead of `strcpy()` and pass in that size argument. This will guard against buffer overflows. Then, you need to allocate more space for your extension buffers.

Comment: That's it! I can't believe I've missed that! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DragosRizescu No problem :) This can be a good lesson on the importance of safe programming practices. Sometimes buffer overruns cause weird behavior that is VERY difficult to track down in large/complex systems, so avoiding them in the first place is very important. Good luck!

Comment: Another option is to have the function return a pointer to the location in the file name where the extension starts.  You should also defined against there being no `.` in the file name.  Are you sure the extension of `.profile` is `.profile`?  (That's debatable both ways — not a statement that you're wrong; it does indicate what you'd get as an extension if you passed `.profile` as a name.

Comment: @dvnrrs I know what mean. First I was using only `bmp` as extension from `santa.bmp` and after I changed, but I forgot to change the size of the string.